# receive data with s.recv()

Tags: python, sockets, gyroscope

I have this little part of code and I think my computer is connected to my sensor (Gyro sensor) but it has a big problem with recv part. With this `s.recv()` part my program stuck and no result. Waiting for idea.
Thanks in advance

```
import socket 

TCP_IP = '......'
TCP_PORT = ....                                      
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

while True:
    data = s.recv(50)
    print data
    if not data:
        break

s.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to connect to the socket ?

Comment: maybe i didnt understand what you said. but i think it is in fifth line of code.

Comment: You really should take a look at the Python socket documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). Read it carefully, socket (in any language) are not easy to understand.

Comment: Here your program is connecting to a remote socket, and without sending any data, just wait for an answer. As we don't know the background infrastructure you're working on, we can not help you that much.

Comment: ok.till now i did it 2 times but as you said i will go for third time.btw thanks for your time

Comment: What is the server doing?  Usually some sort of request is sent to the server by the client first.  Are you sure the server is setup just to send data on a connection?  By the way, the `if` statement should be indented inside the `while` loop, otherwise it is infinite.  Is that a "cut and paste" issue or a genuine bug?

Comment: i connected my laptop to Gyro sensor that continusly give data (angles and speed) via Lan. then i was thinking that Gyroscope is server and my laptop client. it means when it is connected to my laptop via Lan then i can take data with this Lan. about if as you said ,it is inside the loop.

Comment: Could you correct the code in your post then please, it is confusing.

Comment: i did it.sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely to be in the code that sends the data.

However, a few comments with your code here:

- Do a better job to catch exceptions.
- You are asking to recv only a size of 50 in your socket. If the sender sends less that's when you'll get stuck. Check to see what is the length of the data sent by the sender.
- You should not use sockets like that without a timeout.
- Use a print statement after connect to check whether you get stuck in the connect, or in the recv part. That will tell you where to debug your sender code.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i chenge the number and now i have the error like this.                                                                                                       'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 136: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: That's an error probably raised in your print statement. Use print data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')

Comment: no change.the same error. i just hope at least this error show me that i am connected to this Gyro.

Comment: hmm. not sure. I would suggest to run it through a debugger, and see where the error comes from.